# Get instagram photos by Hashtag

Tags: api, instagram, tagname

General issues:
Your screencast does not show a test user logging into Instagram in your app. Please update your screencast to show the complete login experience.
Feedback from your Reviewer:
Thank you for providing such a detailed and descriptive screencast. Unfortunately, I was unable to see the Instagram log in flow or the integration on the site. Please provide a screencast that shows the user linking their account so we can ensure the API is being used properly. Thank you and please resubmit!

Helpppp! what did they mean by that ??

Answer (score 0):

Show screencast of login flow - user clicking on login button, app redirecting to instagram login page, and back to app